# reading data from web page and writing in excel

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to read the data from web page and write in excel.in the web page contains two tables,those table values get extracted and writing it in excel.when extract and print it everything works fine.but it suppose to be write it in excel last row data only writing in all the cell ?

[image] [image]

I thought it's get overriding in the for that I had declared the required data in globally.but no use since the problem remain same.

please find and let me now anything wrong in this below code.

```
Document doc=Jsoup.parse(singleFile, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");
Element table=doc.select("table").get(0);
Element tabl=doc.select("table").get(1);
    Elements rows1=tabl.select("tr");


    Node Avg = null;
    for(int i=1;i< rows1.size();i++){
            Element row1=rows1.get(i);
            Elements col=row1.select("td");

            String Name =col.get(0).text();
            Node Max=col.get(2).childNode(0);
            Avg=col.get(3).childNode(0);

     System.out.println("Name:"+Name+ ": Avg:"+Avg);        

    }    



        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/mramasa7/Desktop/metrics/GUX_BSL Metrics Data_JUN_2019.xlsx"));
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);



        Cell cell=null;

        cell=sheet.getRow(34).getCell(k);
        cell.setCellValue(Avg.toString());
```

Comment: Would you mind rewriting your question? I did not understand what you meant.

Comment: @GabrielPimenta please check out right now I think,I made it as much as possible

Comment: Tried to answer the way I understood it. Hope it helps.

Comment: please let me know if it worked for you. If it did, please also mark the answer as an accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, your problem is that the last value on the original table is being printed in every cell on the excel spreadsheet.

The piece of code that writes on the spreadsheet is the following:

```
cell.setCellValue(Avg.toString());
```

You have not added that piece of code to the loop that creates cells for each entry on your datasource. You should populate rows as you create them. Using Apache POI example:

```
public byte[] export(List<String> exportList) throws Exception{

    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Export");
    for(int i=0; i< exportList.size(); i++) {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
        row.createCell(0)
                .setCellValue(exportList.get(i));
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    workbook.write(bos);
    bos.close();
    return bos.toByteArray();
}
```

For editing existing excel spreadhseet you should use a loop that goes through all existing rows filling it with a desired value. Example:

```
for(int i=0; i< sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
        row.getCell(0)
                .setCellValue(exportList.get(i)); // Insert the number of the cell herer (column)
    }
```

Comment: you have understood correctly.but I am writing data in the existing excel sheet.it mean I am update excel sheet.

Comment: Edited again. The principle of creating/updating spreadsheets is the same. Just locate the cell object you want to change, and change it however you like.

Comment: Did it work for you? Please consider marking my suggestion as a correct answer for future reference.